# Issue with Kaminari while using meta_search for column ordering

Tags: kaminari, meta-search

I am using Kaminari for pagination and trying to use meta_search for column ordering.  I would like my code to look like this:

```
@search = Organization.search(params[:search])
@organizations = @search.page(params[:page])
```

When I write it this way, I am getting the error,

```
undefined method `page' for #<MetaSearch::Builder:0x7fadb8958630>
```

The solution I have found is this:

```
@search = Organization.search(params[:search])
@organizations = Kaminari.paginate_array(@search.all).page(params[:page]
```

It works but feels clunky.  All the examples I have found suggest the first example should work out of the box.  Is there any way to turn the MetaSearch result into an ActiveRecord compatible object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a newer version of meta_search +1.0 it provides integration with Kaminari.